# Safari breaking text underline hover

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm having an issue with text-decoration on safari.

I made a demo and on chrome I have the exact behavior I want but not the same on safari. I want to have a single line underline the container but on safari it appears broken by child element

```
<div class="container">
  <span>TEST</span>
  <span>-</span>
  <span>TEST</span>
</div>
```

Demo here- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrLKVW

Any idea on how to make this consistent ? I've tried applying a border on the bottom but the container has an image in my project (That I don't want underline)

---

@Nenad Vracar your answer works just fine.

@Phil I'm on Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9) and it looks broken... Silly thing but go figure

Comment: Try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrLKjr

Comment: in safari looks okay for me..